# What is meant by indexing a numpy array with a conditional statement based on itself?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, numpy-ndarray, numpy-indexing

I'm working on a large library for network analysis and have come across a perplexing line whose calling convention I'm not familiar with.

```
    monitors = [1,2,3,4]
    nmonitors = 7 # This value is passed arbitrarily to the function

    while len(monitors) < nmonitors:
        remaining = np.arange(len(routers)) # len(routers) here is == 5
        for i in monitors:
            remaining = remaining[remaining != i]
        monitors.append(np.random.choice(remaining))
```

The line in questions in inside the loop which indexes the `remaining` array by a conditional based on `i` and itself. After some debugging it seems to be doing more than just evaluating a bool and indexing the array using that boolean value?

Would anyone be familiar with this syntax/convention and able to point me to the relevant part of numpy documentation or explain? I've been searching for hours with no results still, thank you.

Comment: I think you mean a mask? The mask is a boolean array based on the initial array which is derived through a conditional statement, then you can extract just the `True` values from the array with it.

Comment: So could it possibly relate to the 'boolean indexing' part of the numpy docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There no special syntax, just a combination of generating a boolean array with a conditional test, and indexing an array with a boolean.

A sample array:

```
In [125]: arr = np.arange(4)
In [126]: arr
Out[126]: array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

Indexing with a boolean:

```
In [127]: arr[[True,False,True,False]]
Out[127]: array([0, 2])
```

Creating a boolean with a test:

```
In [128]: (arr%2)==0
Out[128]: array([ True, False,  True, False])
In [129]: arr[(arr%2)==0]
Out[129]: array([0, 2])
```

Or with a test like your example:

```
In [131]: arr!=2
Out[131]: array([ True,  True, False,  True])
In [132]: arr[arr!=2]
Out[132]: array([0, 1, 3])
```

So that inner loop is removing all elements equal to `monitors` from `remaining`, leaving only `[0]`?  The larger loop is buggy, but that has nothing to do with the "syntax" of the boolean indexing.

Answer (score -1):

It returns a new array of Boolean values, the same dimension of the original `remaining`. For each original element of `remaining`, wherever that element is not equal to `i`, the equivalent index in the new array is `true`.